# Place tiles at containers border with isotope?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope, justify

I got a problem with the isotope jquery plugin.

I have several tiles with images that are exactly the same size. Each tile is 49% of it's parent container wide.

How can I get isotope to place all tiles at the containers border like this:

```
|[1]------[2]|
|[3]------[4]|
|[5]------[6]|
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't normally do that, without added custom layout methods to Isotope, as it places items relative to their top left corner.

You can however fake the effect by having your tiles within larger transparent tiles that Isotope actually manages.

```
|[[1]<--][-->[2]]|
|[[3]<--][-->[4]]|
|[[5]<--][-->[6]]|
```